# What are various types of supports required in slicing the CAD model?

Tags: print-quality, support-structures

Also, a visualization of the various types of supports required in slicing the CAD model is a plus.

I'm just getting started with Rapid prototyping and I had no idea about that. Is there any type of support we can select in the software settings or will it always get generated automatically?

Comment: I do not understand your question. What do you mean by that a type of support is "required"? Supports are normally automatically generated by the slicer.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm just getting started with Rapid prototyping and I had no idea about that. Is there any type of support we can select in the software settings or will it always get generated automatically?

Comment: If you just want to see the different types of support pattern, you can just use the preview mode of the slicer. For example in Cura select one of the patterns and switch to layer view. Now you can see what would be printed layer by layer. Is that what you are asking for?

Answer (score 2):

Support structure generation depends on the type of slicer you use to convert your model (STL model file) into printable code (G-code) for the 3D printer. Different options and solutions exist to add support depending on the slicer software applications. Alternatively, you could add your own supports to your models in 3D CAD programs.

Without giving an opinion on the slicer applications, the most commonly used slicers are Cura and Slic3r (both free) and Simplifi3d (paid license). Please choose your software and do some more investigations on setting up these applications for slicing and address your question with a more specific question.

Comment: Alternately, for simple models requiring simple support (like a single overhang), some prefer to design in a sacrificial support element to their model.